# fgets doesn't wait for input in parent process but it does in the child one

Tags: c, linux, input, fork, fgets

This is an external function that sets environment variables

```
int mini_read(char ** variables){
    if(variables[1] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[100];
    fgets(buf, 100, stdin);

        //I doubt the bug is below here
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
    char ** valores = NULL;
    char * valor = strtok(buf, " \t");
    valores[0] = valor;
    int i = 1;
    // Guardar valores en array
    while(valor != NULL){
        valor = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        valores[i] = valor;
        i++;
    }
    for(int i = 1; ; i++){
        if(valores[i-1] == NULL) break;
        //printf("variables[%d]: %s\n valor[%d]: %c\n", i, variables[i], i, valor[i]);
        if(variables[i] == NULL){
            char*fin = NULL;
            //Si hay más valores que variables, concatenar valores
            for(int j = i-1; valores[j] != NULL; j++){
                printf("%s\n", fin);
                strcat(fin, valores[j]);
            }
            printf("%s\n", fin);
            setenv(variables[i-1], fin, 1);
            break;
        }
        setenv(variables[i], valores[i-1], 1);
    }
    return 0;
```

Then I want to call the function in the parent process because if I call it from the child process the environment variables don't get set "globally".
If I call it from the child process it works just fine; however, if I call it from the parent process, `fgets`() doesn't wait for input.

```
int main(void){


pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        //Option 1
        if(strcmp(argv[0], "read") == 0) mini_read(argv);
    }

    else{
        //Option 2
        if(strcmp(argv[0], "read") == 0) mini_read(argv);

        waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);      
    }
}
```

Comment: `valores[0] = valor;` incurs undefined behavior, since `valores == NULL`.

Comment: miguelrr_11, Does code use `scnaf()` elsewhere?  That is a likely source of a problem.